# trigger.io: Web view for header?

Tags: trigger.io

Using trigger.io, is there a way of specifying a web view for the header area?

I currently have a rather complex header that utilises media queries and includes an input box  depending on the current screen width. This extends far beyond what the trigger.io's native topbar implementation is capable of so I was wondering if this is possible or is potentially planned?

At the moment I'm utilizing position fixed for devices that are known to support it, but it would be nice to have full support on all devices (mainly Android 2.3>*).

Comment: maybe iScroll is what you need: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: iScroll would be overkill in my case. I'm happy to fall back on a static header on older devices if what I'm asking is not possible with trigger.io.

Comment: This is not currently possible with our native topbar component. For the flexibility that you need, it sounds like you'd be best off with implementing the header in HTML / CSS. We don't have plans to offer the topbar as a separate webview, but are interested in getting your take on that and learning the details of the requirement - email support@trigger.io